# What is the most efficient structure to work with datestamped data

Tags: c#, linq, sorting, ienumerable

Fellow coders,

I've a method which returns an IEnumerable(T) where T contains a DateTime property.

I need to perform many date-based extractions from this set of data : all items which are in between Date1 and Date2 for example.

As the dataset is getting bigger, I am facing a performance issue : those extractions take a while. I feel it can be optimized by chosing a better suited data structure to enumerate to.

What I am doing right now is :

```
              public class Foo
    {
        public DateTime Date { get; set; }
        public double Value { get; set; }
    }


    public class DoSomething
    {
        public IEnumerable<Foo> Foos { get;}

        public IEnumerable<Foo[]> DoStuff(DateTime[] dates)
        {
            var foos = Foos.
                OrderBy(x=>x.Date)
                .ToArray(); //Prevents multiple enumeration later on, Any better suited structure ? 

            for (int i = 0; i < dates.Length-1; i++)
            {
                yield return foos
                    .Where(x => x.Date > dates[i])
                    .Where(y=>y.Date<dates[i+1])
                    .ToArray();
            }
        }
    }
```

I've read that the LINQ method OrderBy creates an IOrderEnumerable, but I feel that enumerating it to an array *destroys* the logical order geween items. How can I prevent multiple enumerating **and** keep the order relationship for further uses?

Comment: Your issue is that loop.  Say `foos` contains 10,000 items.  Once per each item, you loop through the *entire* collection of `foos`.  You do that 10,000 times.  You don't appear to be using the loop index parameter `i` anywhere that I can see.  I see no purpose to that loop... What is it's intended purpose?

Comment: This loop is just an example, it's an artefact for explaining that I need to do this operation many times, sorry if this is misleading.

Comment: It's very misleading.  Your example should be illustrative or representative of your actual situation.  (This is why I didn't write that as an answer - something felt *off*)

Comment: When you `ToArray`, the resulting IEnumerable (array) is guaranteed to be in the correct order each and every time that you enumerate it. As an aside, you don't seem to be using `i`, the loop variable. From the looks of it, you're yielding several (`foos.Length`) arrays with exactly the same contents for each array yielded. What am I missing?

Comment: @Amy Ok, I modified it, so there is no more confusion

Comment: @XavierAM With the edit, the question makes makes more sense.  Thanks.

Comment: @spender So at every _extraction_, the method doesn't need to go through the whole array (and stops when it has found a date superior to the max date)? As it would be the case in an HashSet for example?

Comment: In the example above, are the dates that you are seaching also in order?

Comment: @spender no, I should assume that they are not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The slowest point in your algorithm, by far, is 2-times `Where`. Always remember: `Where` is always very slow for big collections and also for more complex comparison functions.

So here is a better algorithm: I would replace these two `Where` by a custom binary search. Time complexity of `Where` is `O(n)`, while complexity of binary search is `O(log n)`. The purpose of the binary search is to find the closest element to the marginal date, in other words you are going to find the smallest date in `foo` collection which is bigger than `dates[i]` and then, separately, you are going to find the biggest date than is smaller than `dates[i+1]`.

reference: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm

So you write two helper methods to find lower and upper bound items in `foo`, then you can simply yield the interval as you do now.

Also, you can get another tiny improvement by replacing `Foos.OrderBy.ToArray` by `Foos.Sort` or `Foos.Clone.Sort`. You will just need to supply a comparison function. (But this refactoring is not as important as the above one.)

By using this approach, you can get time complexity in order O(m.log n), instead of your current O(m.n) where n is size of collection and m is number of date pairs.

Comment: Hmm, ok I'll have a look. Actually, I wrote the two sequential where statement for better readability but the way it's implemented in the code is : `.Where(x => x.Date > dates[i] && x.Date<dates[i+1])` I guess it doesn't change the O(n) complexity, does it? And, just one more question, is there any off-the-shelf structure which implements a binary search algorithm or should I create a custom one?

Comment: @XavierAM Good old `List<T>` includes a `BinarySearch` method.

Comment: @spender yes but that is based on simple equality. Here we need to find closest date, not equal, so the implementation needs to be different.